# MeCab Not Parsing Correctly

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-science, tokenize, mecab

I downloaded MeCab to parse some Japanese text. To test it out, I tried doing what some examples online showed.

For example, I followed this guy's tips verbatim: http://www.robfahey.co.uk/blog/japanese-text-analysis-in-python/

The code is as follows:

```
import MeCab

test = "今日はいい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！"
mt = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen -d /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd")
parsed = mt.parseToNode(test)

components = []
while parsed:
    components.append(parsed.surface)
    parsed = parsed.next

print(components)
```

The output that I'm expecting is:

```
['', '今日', 'は', 'いい', '天気', 'です', 'ね', '。', '遊び', 'に', '行か', 'ない', '？', '新宿', 'で', '祭り', 'が', 'ある', '！', '']
```

However, I'm getting this:

```
['今日はいい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', '今日はいい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'はいい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'いい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', '天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'ね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', '。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', '遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'に行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', '行かない？新宿で祭りがある！', 'ない？新宿で祭りがある！', '？新宿で祭りがある！', '新宿で祭りがある！', 'で祭りがある！', '祭りがある！', 'がある！', 'ある！', '！', '']
```

To anyone familiar with MeCab or parsing node in general, what exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, there's a [bug](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues/19) in the latest version of `mecab-python3` that was released in November.

The bug should be fixed soon, but for now please use version 0.7.